# Can I use a single snubber circuit for multiple triacs?

Tags: triac, snubber

I am building a triac sprinkler controller using BT136S-800,118 triacs with a microcontroller for control.  The triac driver (MOC3021M) suggests a snubber circuit for an inductive load.

I have two questions about the circuit.

1. As the title suggests, I am curious if I can use a single snubber circuit for all of the drivers.
2. Since my circut is running 24vac vs 120vac , should I reduce the resistor values by 5x since the voltage will be ~ 5x less?

datasheets for [MOC3021M driver](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MOC3023M_D-2316077.pdf) and [BT136S-800 triac](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/70e184bc3b57661ea11b1a0bebf5607c836bfba1/bt136s-800.pdf)

Suggested Snubber Circuit

[image: datasheet suggested snubber Design]

Hopefully you can follow this schematic.  This is my idea for a single snubber for these three triac drivers.

[image: Proposed Multiple Triac Circuits]

Comment: Snubbers protect the switch and not the grid, so Answer:NO  But you can get snuberless Triacs with internal capacitance.  But the protection is from dV/dt across anode-cathode , not the gate current

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, I would say no. The purpose of the using the optical triac to switch a larger triac is to allow for a snubber for an appropriate zero crossing so the large triac is not switching when large amounts of a current a flowing through it (and exceeding the dv/dt limit). The other purpose for using a larger snubber is most opti-triacs (or whatever they are called) do not support large amounts of current. Most people need to switch amps of current.

The design probably doesn't need a snubber (that being said you would probably want separate out the snubber if you do need it so when one load is switched off and the other switched on

You probably couldn't exceed the dv/dt limit for either optotriac as the MOC's are 1000V/us and the other one is 250V/us, it would probably be really hard to generate  those kind of voltages in with a sprinkler valve solenoid. So a snubber would not be necessary.

I would also think that you could drive the solenoid directly with the optotriac could be done if you don't exceed the RMS on-state current or the peak on state current.

I would try and just do a bench setup and see how the optotriacs handle the abuse of the solenoid if you don't want to simulate or calculate the current, before building the PCB.

Comment: Where are you getting the 1000V/us for the dv/dt for the MOC?  All I can find is a graph of dv/dt vs temperature and that shows it between 10V/us to 1.8v/us.

Comment: I got it here, I didn't see your link: https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-99-0019/MOC302X%20series%20201606.pdf

Comment: thank you for that.  I thought 10v/us seemed low.  I did try to drive the solenoid with just the MOC and experienced what other people have reported, that it gets stuck on.  I tried setting up the snubber circuit and it still didn't shut off, but then again I hate breadboarding so no guarantees it's set up correctly.